# Issues with Jquery function that will unhide a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The fiddle attached is a working copy of what I want: http://jsfiddle.net/DLEBf/2/

It's not working in my code though.

Here's my code:

HTML: `<div class="listResults"></div>`

JS:

```
function createMarker(latlng, address) {
    var html =  "<br/>" + address;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: latlng
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    markers.push(marker);

    $(function(){
        $('.listResults').on('click', '.heading',  function(){
           $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
        });

        var el = $('<div/>', {
        'class' : 'heading',
        'html' : 'Header-1'
        });
        var content = $('<div/>', { 
        'class' : 'content',
        'style' : 'display:none',
        'html' : 'This is content'
        })
        $('.listResults').append(el);
        el.after(content);
    });
```

}

Comment: Ok? What's not working about it?

Comment: The $function(){} code doesn't work. If i comment it out the code compiles fine. Otherwise it doesn't work. Do you see something wrong with the placement of that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the `$(function(){})` part there should be a `(jQuery);`, and you need to pass `$` as a parameter like so:

```
(function($){
    ...
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks. Now i just need to figure out where to put the code below that will unhide the div. I need it to work exactly like the fiddle. any ideas? $('.listResults').on('click', '.heading',  function(){

$(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
});

Comment: This overcomplicates the solution. All you need is the () to call the function; sending jQuery as a parameter is not needed, because the function is within the scope of the parent function. In other words, get rid of the "$" and "jQuery" but keep the brackets.

Comment: So, you want it like this? http://jsfiddle.net/7GJDu/ Where does the $('.listresults) go?

Comment: @Denver That code should work fine anywhere that jQuery will work because it is just an event handler.

Comment: The code doesn't go beyond that unless i slap it in another <script> tag up top. It compiles after that but doesn't unhide the div

Comment: @Denver That Fiddle also doesn't have a div in it.

Comment: @Denver I fixed that fiddle you posted: http://jsfiddle.net/7GJDu/1/

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/DLEBf/6/ but not in my code. Here's my current code: http://jsfiddle.net/DLEBf/7/

Comment: Something to do with it being in that createmarker function messes it up.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25483/discussion-between-denver-and-alex-w)

Comment: Yeah i know. It doesn't work when it's executed. That .listresults doesn't work.

Comment: @Denver The way the code currently is, nothing will happen when you click the `.listResults` div *unless* you have executed the `createMarker` function already. If you take it out of the `createMarker()` function it will probably work as expected.

Comment: When my code runs i know that the createmarker is executed. It plants markers on a google map. I want it to create those divs as each marker is placed. The code continues through if i comment out the .listresults. If i put the .listresults outside of createmarker the code executes as required BUT it doesn't unhide the div when clicked.

Comment: @Denver Try moving that code to the very end of the function.

Comment: Nope. doesn't work. Really bizarre.

Comment: @Denver Use this instead of `.on()`: `$(document).delegate(".listResults",'click',function(){...});`

Comment: Wow that's close. Now it generates all of the heading elements (over 20 in this case). It doesn't unhide when i clikc it though. http://jsfiddle.net/DLEBf/8/

Comment: @Denver try changing the selector from `.listResults` to `.heading` for that line of code.

Comment: That actually did the trick. I moved it out of the createmarker function too and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot!